# Is there any chemical preservative better than sodium benzoate?

Tags: food-chemistry

I'm developing a fruit juice for humans, I just want a second opinion about allowed food preservatives. Does anyone happen to know if there are any chemical preservatives that can extend the shelf life of fruit juice better than sodium benzoate?

Comment: >I'm experimenting with various preservatives   | DO NOT. I'm serious. Most preservatives used are slightly to seriously toxic when used in wrong amounts. Using them wrong way is a guaranteed way to troubles.

Comment: I'm a chemical engineer and I think I know what I'm doing. I just want to know if any know a better preservative.

Comment: Yes - mix the fruit juice with lots of formaldehyde. Oh, you meant better in the sense of still being consumable by a human without adverse side effects? Well, that is a very different question, and while some chemical engineering is good, a lot of toxicology is required as well...

Comment: @user3754535 Not relevant. Toxicology/biology background is required.  In case you are interested in what may be used, consider looking for a 'list of permitted preservatives' (ideally several such lists from several different countries should be referenced). However again, no 'experimentation' here, only allowed methods/proportions are to be used.

Comment: Did you think about $\gamma$-iradiation using $\ce{^{60}Co}$?

Comment: @permeakra I just a simple question,What is the best preservative (allowed of course) for fruit juice? or physical preservative techniques . I can't believe you guys go deep so fast. I you don't know other chemical for this matter I will answer the question myself, I just wanted a second opinion.

Comment: @JonCuster I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want a second opinion about allowed food preservatives.

**Allowed** is crucial here and it might strongly depend of where the product is to be sold. You might want to have a look at national legislations.

- For Germany, the [Zusatzstoff-Zulassungsverordnung](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bundesrecht/zzulv_1998/gesamt.pdf) lists allowed preservatives and their maximum concentrations in different products.
- For Canada, *Health Canada* provides a [List of Permitted Preservatives](http://www.hc-sc.gc.ca/fn-an/securit/addit/list/11-preserv-conserv-eng.php).